# Different value of csrf token in response header and browser cookies. csrf verification failing in django 1.9

Tags: django, cookies, django-admin

**Most of the SO answers are asking to clear cookies and confirm middleware class. I have already tried that.**

Python - 3.4
Django - 1.10
Using VirtualEnv.

I am getting `Forbidden (403) CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.` error on Django admin login screen. I have hosted my site on pythonanywhere.com with django **version 1.9**.

- I have cleared the browser cookies. All of them.
- I reloaded the login screen. Get request.
- In browser cookies, which were empty till now, one value has been set for my website, where csrf value is = `XPp5hAhylAkt27U4SzGPNU7w8SFBJ3RP` 
  [image]
- In response header, set cookies was send with cookies value = `UT24544MghHLZi0IrGHQlCcpk1v0SbCy`  . Same value was available in form's source code.
  [image]
- Now I entered the username and password and click on login button.
- Received the 403 error CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.
- I rechecked all the values of csrf token.
- In request header CSRF cookies values = `XPp5hAhylAkt27U4SzGPNU7w8SFBJ3RP`
  [image]
- In form data csrf values = `UT24544MghHLZi0IrGHQlCcpk1v0SbCy`
  [image]
- I already have 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware', in middleware classes. I cleared browser cache and cookies. Even restarted the system.

I have used exactly same code on different site where it is working perfectly fine.

Why there are different csrf-token values? What is the solution to this problem?

update 1: If I set debug = False in settings, it works fine. But I cant keep it as code is live.

**update 2**: Upon further investigation I found out that somehow browser cookie csrftoken's value is not being set to correct value which is being passed in response header. If I delete and the cookie from browser and then set it to correct value from console, post requests work.

**update 3** : Now same issue is happening with every post request or form submission I am doing on my web app. CSRF token value sent in response header and source code is not same as the one being set in browser cookies.

update 4: Setting CSRF_COOKIE_NAME = "csrf_token" also didn't helped.

Comment: Are you actually putting the CSRF token into your form?

Comment: Hi Glen, this is admin module, so any form created inside admin module must have csrf token.

Comment: Did you set CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE to True perhaps ?

Comment: @zxzak : No I didn't. and default is false.

Comment: Read All About {{ csrf_token }} 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/csrf/

Comment: @User42 How are you sending your csrf token? Using javascript with `var csrftoken = Cookies.get('csrftoken');`? Or Django templating `<form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}`?

Comment: @kshikama - I am using <form>{% csrf_token %}</form> method

Comment: what is your python version and used browser?

Comment: have you seen this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38302058/django-csrf-cookie-not-set-correctly ?

Comment: Are you using some kind of special setup to access that site? E.g. a proxy that changes URLs? Is there maybe any kind of resource in the page your are accessing that sets a different cookie?

Comment: @DanielHepper - No special setup. Just using wsgi. Hosted on pythonanywhere.com.  Exactly same setup is being used in other website where things are working fine. It looks browser issue to me. 100rupeekar.com -> working fine. 10dollarkart.com -> issue here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The unexpected value for the CSRF token is set when the browser tries to fetch the favicon.

The URL you have defined for your favicon seems to be invalid, and apparently, non-existing URLs are handled by your default view. This sets a different CSRF cookie, but the page that is displayed in the browser still has the initial CSRF token in the form.

Request loading the page:
[image]

Request loading the favicon:
[image]

You can fix this particular error by ensuring that the favicon exists.

Note this this bug will come back whenever any resource you link (e.g. an image) does not exist because your app renders the homepage instead of returning a 404 error.

Comment: Thanks a lot Daniel. I am using HomePage view for handling mistyped urls. Is it possible that home page is loaded when someone type wrong url but just ignore when images are not found.

Comment: A good solution depends on how you implemented that fallback. It's probably best to ask a new question for that. As a workaround, you could check in your `HomePage` view if `request.path` starts with `/static/` and return a 404 response.

Comment: Oh my goodness, thank you for posting this. I've been trying to sort this error for a few days now and it absolutely stumped me. Can't believe it was something like this which was causing the error.

Comment: I would have never thought of this! Unfortunately, I set the favicon correctly now, and still I get the same error. :-(

Comment: @DanielHepper why setting debug = False solved this problem?

Comment: @AmitTripathi I think that this is a typo and that it is the other way around, setting DEBUG = True solves the problem. I'm not sure why it makes a difference, my guess is that Django's static file serving is used in debug mode, which returns a 404 for non-existing files and doesn't set a CSRF token.