# Django CSRF Failure After Upgrade 1.9 > 1.11

Tags: django, csrf

I've just upgraded an app I'm developing from 1.9 to 1.11 and am getting constant errors on all form posts:

```
CSRF token missing or incorrect.
```

All CSRF tokens were working fine in 1.9. Here is the view:

```
def contact(request):
    subject = request.GET.get('subject', '')
    contact_form = forms.ContactForm(subject=subject)

    if request.POST:
        contact_form = forms.ContactForm(request.POST)

        if contact_form.is_valid():
            new_contact = contact_form.save()
            logic.send_contact_message(new_contact, request)
            messages.add_message(request, messages.SUCCESS, 'Your message has been sent.')
            return redirect(reverse('contact'))

    template = 'journal/contact.html'
    context = {
        'contact_form': contact_form,
        'contacts': core_models.Contacts.objects.filter(content_type=request.content_type,
                                                    object_id=request.site_type.pk)
    }

    return render(request, template, context)
```

Here is the template:

```
            <h4>{% trans "Contact" %}</h4>
            <form method="POST">
                {% include "elements/forms/errors.html" with form=contact_form %}
                {% csrf_token %}
                <label for="id_recipient">{% trans "Who would you like to contact?" %}</label>
                <select id="id_recipient" name="recipient">
                    {% for contact in contacts %}<option value="{{ contact.email }}">{{ contact.name }}, {{ contact.role }}</option>{% endfor %}
                </select>
                {{ contact_form.sender|foundation }}
                {{ contact_form.subject|foundation }}
                {{ contact_form.body|foundation }}
                {{ contact_form.are_you_a_robot|foundation }}
                <button type="submit" class="success button">{% trans "Send Message" %}</button>
            </form>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Django 1.10 [introduced salted CSRF tokens that change every time the user logs in](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/csrf/#how-it-works):

> **Changed in Django 1.10:**
>
> Added salting to the token and started changing it with each request to protect against [BREACH](http://breachattack.com/) attacks.

You will have to log out and back in again to generate a new salted token before your forms will work.

Melvyn suggests clearing your session store in a comment. That would work too, and is probably a better option if you have many users.

You might also have to modify your middleware settings to reflect [the new style introduced in Django 1.10](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/releases/1.10/#new-style-middleware). The [old `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` setting is deprecated](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#std:setting-MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES) in favour of `MIDDLEWARE`. Make sure that `'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware'` is included in your `MIDDLEWARE`.  If you have custom middleware (or if you're using libraries that use old-style middleware) it will have to be updated.

Comment: Or clear the session store (which will log out all users). Painful, but necessary.

Comment: Great point, @Melvyn. That's definitely better if there are many users. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for this, cleared the session table and cleared browser cookies but still getting a CSRF error when trying to log in...

Comment: @ajrbyers, are you trying to log in via the standard admin login page, or do you have a custom login page? If the latter, have you tried the former?

Comment: @Chris thanks, I've tried with both login pages and various other POSTs that don't require login, to no avail. Could there be something in a middleware breaking it?

Comment: @ajrbyers, ah, yes! Middleware was changed in 1.10 as well. I've updated my answer; hopefully that will help.